# O Crontab não mata os processos depois de eles acabarem?

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

Estou a usar o [Crontab](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab) para me executar um script PHP a cada 10 minutos o problema é que vão ficando os processos a correr no servidor, ou seja a cada 10 minutos tenho mais um processo a correr.

```
crontab -e 

*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/test/test.php
```

O [Crontab](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab) não mata os processos depois de eles acabarem? Ou tenho de fazer alguma coisa no script PHP para que o processo termine?

Comment: É que é só uma inserção na BD MySQL o script...

Comment: Você está executando a cada 5 minutos. Já verificou se o processo está sendo executado no banco de dados ? Dá a impressão que a sua rotina está em execução e a cada 5 novos minutos entra outra conexão, verifique no banco de dados ou aumente o tempo da execução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Cron é só um agendador de tarefas, ou seja o crontab, seu utlitario de configuração, não mata processos somente os executa no horário que eles foram agendados.

Para que seus processos sejam finalizados seu script PHP tem que finalizar de alguma forma, não sei o conteúdo dele para poder dizer o que voce tem que fazer, mas como disse o Cron não faz isto ele só é um agendador de tarefas